# validation error in JSON

Tags: django, json

I have added a field as JSONField and saves it to a django model. The data are getting saved in dictionary format. But when i take that model in admin, it shows me "Validation Error: [u'Enter valid JSON']". What does this error means? Any Help.

models.py:

udf5 = JSONField(_('UDF5'),  max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the JSON you are inserting is wrong,  to validate your JSON you can use [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) for example

Comment: @JithinShaji It provides an answer, besides the question doesn't provide the JSON so we can't help him validating it, this is the reason I suggested jsonlint